# is there a better way to do this conidition?

Tags: react-native, expo

is there a better way to do this :

```
      { !AuthState && (
      <NativeStackNavigator.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} options={{headerShown: false}} />)
      }

      { !AuthState && (
      <NativeStackNavigator.Screen name="XXX" component={XXX} options={{headerShown: false}} />)
      }

      { !AuthState && (
      <NativeStackNavigator.Screen name="XXX" component={XXX} options={{headerShown: false}} />)
      }
```

thanks for your answer!

Comment: Why does it repeat 3 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the conditional for all screens once.

```js
{
   !AuthState && (
     <>
      <NativeStackNavigator.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      <NativeStackNavigator.Screen name="XXX" component={XXX} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      <NativeStackNavigator.Screen name="XXX" component={XXX} options={{headerShown: false}} />
   </>
    )
}
```